# Replace underscores in Entity Mappings

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4, entity, edmx, database-first

When using EF4 to create a model, I would like to replace all underscores as well as table/column prefixes so that the model reads cleanly. Our database has a structure something like:

```
Table:ABC_Customer
-Column:ABC_Customer_Id
-Column:Name
-Column:ABC_Customer_Type_Id

Table:ABC_Customer_Type
-Column:ABC_Customer_Type_Id
-Column:Name
```

I would like to have entities names like so:

```
Entity:Customer
-Property:CustomerId
-Property:Name
-Property:CustomerTypeId
-NavigationProperty:CustomerType
```

and so on and so on.

When generating the edmx file, the EF designer names all the entities exactly as they appear in the database. I know this behavior can be modified using the T4 templates, but I just discovered that I can rename the entities in the designer, which generates EntitySetMapping elements within the edmx file, so T4 seems like overkill. It almost seems like I just want to post-process the edmx file, without using the T4 templates since after that replacement, I want the default behavior. Which approach is the most approriate and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDMX is responsible for mapping and any new names should be defined in mapping = in EDMX.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the out of the box functionality unless I was dealing with a **very large** number of tables.  The time investment to get the T4 templates to do exactly what you need may not be worth it.

For a small database I would stick with the designer if doing *database first* development.

Alternatively, you could go *code first* to get a clean model like you want, point it at your existing database and handle the mappings in code for each object in the model:

```
public class CustomerConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public CustomerConfiguration()
    {
        Property(t => t.CustomerId).HasColumnName("ABC_Customer_Id");
        ...
    }
}
```

And then apply your custom configurations (i.e. mappings) to the model at the same time you change the table mappings:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CustomerConfiguration());

    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable("ABC_Customer");
}
```

The more I work with it, the more I like code first.  Julie Lerman's new book [Programming Entity Framework: Code First](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/book/downloads-for-code-first-book/) is great!

Comment: The database is farily large (100+ tables and 1200+ columns), so the designer will be tedious, and potentially error prone. Code first is not an option as the database has pre-existed for a long time. We've been using strongly typed datasets to date, but would like to switch to EF.

Comment: @mhildreth Code first **is** designed to work with existing databases.  I'm not keen on navigating around a large model in the designer and mapping window trying to figure out what mappings I have.  With the code first approach I know any mappings I have for the Foo table are in the FooConfiguration.cs file.